# How to know if something is installed?

Tags: ps4, the-division

I purchased the season pass on the playstation store for the game "the Division".
How would I check to see if its installed in the game?

Answer (score 1):

It should be installed when you bought it or put in the code for it, so when the next map pack is available just start the download that's how all season passes work.

Answer (score 1):

Season passes are not downloadable, they just unlock DLC's automatically (not free DLC's).

But you should be able to see it: Go to your Library on your PS4 -> select The Division -> You should see the Overview, scroll down untill you see My Add-Ons -> Click on it and it should be listed there.

Answer (score 1):

Also, since the latest DLC for season pass holders is apparently 8 "free" high-end materials, you could just turn on the game and see if they're present at your rewards vendor.

Comment: Visiting the rewards vendor is the best way I think, as season pass holders will have lots of available items.